# If $\gcd(\gcd(a, b),\gcd(a, c))=1$, then $\gcd(a, bc) = \gcd(a, b) \cdot \gcd(a, c)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

> Let $a, b$ and $c$ be integers. Prove that if $\gcd(a, b)$ and $\gcd(a, c)$ are
>   coprime, then $\gcd(a, bc)$ = $\gcd(a, b) · \gcd(a, c)$

I am stumped in this problem. Can anybody clarify me what does $\gcd(a, b)$ and $\gcd(a, c)$ are coprime mean? Is that mean that $\gcd(a, b)$ = $\gcd(a, c) = 1$ ? Any hints on how to approach such problem? Thanks!

Comment: If $d_1 = \gcd(a,b), d_2=\gcd(a,c)$ then $\gcd(d_1,d_2) = 1$.

Comment: “$p$ and $q$ are coprime” means that $\gcd(p,q)=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x=\text{gcd}(a,b)$ and $y=\text{gcd}(a,c)$. We'll prove that $xy=\text{gcd}(a,bc)$ by showing $xy|\text{gcd}(a,bc)$ and $\text{gcd}(a,bc)|xy$.

First, $\text{gcd}(x,y)=1$ so there are integers $m,n$ such that $1=mx+ny$ which implies 
$$
a=m(xa)+n(ya).
$$
Because $x|a$ and $y|a$, the RHS above is divisible by $xy$. This means the LHS $a$ is also divisible by $xy$. Moreover, $x|b$ and $y|c$ so $xy|bc$. Thus, $xy$ is a common divisor of $a$ and $bc$. In particular, $xy|\text{gcd}(a,bc)$.

Now, it remains to demonstrate that $\text{gcd}(a,bc)|xy$. For this, we can multiply the Bezout's identities for $x=\text{gcd}(a,b)$ and $y=\text{gcd}(a,c)$ to see that there are integers $r$ and $s$ satisfying:
$$
xy=ar+(bc)s.\tag{A}
$$
This implies $\text{gcd}(a,bc)|xy$, which completes our proof.

**Edit**: More details to get (A): write
$$
x=ap+bq,\quad y=au+cv
$$
and multiply to get
$$
xy=a\underbrace{(apu+cpv+bqu)}_r+(bc)\underbrace{(qv)}_s.
$$

Comment: i don't get when you multiply the Bezout's Identity... can you explain that to me?

Comment: @Aaron: see edit.

Comment: thats super clear now! thank you!!!

Comment: I have another question... i am just wondering whether my reasoning is correct or not. just from $xy=ar+(bc)s$ this, we can deduce that $xy = gcd (a,bc)$ by EEA. is that true?